# Error Could not find valid session key wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Inside hook_civicrm_post, when I comment 
the below line

> $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id,'user_email' =>
>   $objectRef[Email1]));

It does not give "Could not find valid key" error 
but when I uncomment the above line it gives the error

Kindly let me know how I can fix this

```
$user_id  = $uf_match['values'][$uf_match['id']]['uf_id'];
        $data = get_userdata($user_id);
        if ($data->user_mail != $objectRef[Email1]){
         //$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id,'user_email' => $objectRef[Email1]));
        }
```

Comment: What kind of entity are you working on in the callback to `hook_civicrm_post`? As I mention in a comment on Jon's answer, there a number of complications related to updates of the Contact's email address.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no WordPress expert, but my reading of the codex is that `wp_update_user()` will remove cookies for the logged-in user. The docs say it "Uses: `wp_clear_auth_cookie()`".

I would try to do the same with [wp_insert_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) instead, it says in the codex that this can update OR create new users.

Comment: I have used update_user_meta instead and that seems to work  update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_email', $objectRef[Email1]);

Comment: The answer is not quite correct: `wp_update_user()` only refreshes the auth cookie if the password has been changed for the currently logged-in user. FWIW, CiviCRM itself uses `wp_update_user()` to update the email address of a synced contact: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php#L580